# Add or remove individual column in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently writing a script where the user needs to add data to a table, but he can use an add button to add another column and this needs to be done on each individual row. Also, I would need a remove button which comes up next to each information as you mouse over each bit of information.

At the minute I have a static table where it has two columns on each row like this...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Row1 Column1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val2">Row2 Column1</input>//Remove btn on mouseover</td>
    </tr>//Add btn
    <tr>
        <td>Row1 Column2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val2">Row2 Column2</input>//Remove btn on mouseover</td>//Add btn
    </tr>
</table>
```

What would I need to dynamically add and/or remove each item, Javascript or jQuery?

Do you know any tutorials which could help with this?

My Javascript and jQuery knowledge is pretty much void since I haven't looked at it in over a year.

Comment: You can use the `addNode` function for the rows, but the table cells are nodes of the rows, you would probably need to iterate through the rows to add/remove cells.

Comment: Never heard of the addnot function, is this in PHP or JS? and how would I go about implementing it?

Comment: You have two questions here: one is about how to add/remove columns to HTML tables client-side, the other is about how to use PHP to record the new table structure. Edit this question to work out which of those questions you want answered here, and ask another question (after first searching the site) to address the second question.

Comment: The `addNode` function is Javascript, except I think I have named the wrong function. I just looked at my old code, and it turns out to add rows you can use `table.insertRow(table.rows.length)`, and to remove them, you use `table.removeChild(/*getElementById*/)`.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a go. How would I do it with each row, I know I would put it into a function and call the function with each new row but how would the function know which row to add or remove the column to? It's been ages since I last looked did some proper JS so my skills are rusty. Think I might need to hit some books and sites.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tableaddcolumn.html

Then use jquery to post the info to your server and a php handler to handle the info and save it.

Comment: I've had a look at that tutorial, but it's not exactly to my taste and still doesn't answer my whole list of questions.Thanks for the answer any way.